# C++ Error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*'

Tags: c++

I know that this question has been asked before many times on stackoverflow, but there just wasn't a question similar to mine.

So I am having the above mentioned error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*'

I don't think the 'is_distinct(string year)' function has anything to do with this but I pasted it just in case.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int to_int(string number);
string to_str(int number);
bool is_distinct(string year);

int main()
{
    string year = "";
    cout << "Enter a word: ";
    getline(cin, year);
    // given the year, 'year', we are to find the next year with distinct digits
    int int_year = to_int(year) + 1;
    while (1 == 1) {
        int year = to_int(year);
        string year = to_str(year);
        if (is_distinct(year)) {
            cout << year << endl;
            break;
        }

        else {
            year += 1;
        }
    }


    if (is_distinct(year)) {
        cout << year << " is a distinct year.";
    }

    else {
        cout << year << " is not a distinct year.";
    }
    return 0;
}

int to_int(string number) {
    int integer;
    istringstream(number) >> integer;
    return integer;
}

string to_str(int number) {
    stringstream ss;
    ss << number;
    string str = ss.str();
    return str;
}

bool is_distinct(string year) {
    bool distinct = true;
    for (unsigned int x = 0; x < year.length(); x++) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (unsigned int y = x+1; y < year.length(); y++) {
            if (year[x] == year[y]) {
                counter += 1;
            }
        }
        if (counter > 0) {
            distinct = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return distinct;
}
```

Comment: in the while loop `1 == 1` can be written as `true` or just `1` which may be easier to read.

Comment: You can not have multiple variables of the same name. int year, and then string year on the next line.

Comment: Where is the error message you mentioned?

Comment: Never go cliff-diving with a guy named Cliff... Just... too many cliffs. (and in this case, too many `year`s). The compiler isn't just giving you that error message, there are plenty of other errors and/or warnings. Heed them.

Answer (score 3):

> int year = to_int(year);

The `year` you are passing to `to_int` is the same `int year` you've just declared, **not** `string year` declared at the top of `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop should probably look like this:

```
while (1){
    int_year = to_int(year);
    if (is_distinct(year)) {
        cout << year << endl;
        break;
    }

    else {
        year = to_str(int_year+1);
    }
}
```